# Why (sender as "something") have null value in c# windows forms app

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to write an form_close event in C# windows forms app that will do different things depending on what control launched application close.

I have

```
    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
```

to close application from main menu, and

```
    private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sender as ToolStripMenuItem).Name == @"exitToolStripMenuItem")
        { }
}
```

to process form_closing, and show different message depending on control.

Problem is, that value of "`sender as toolstripmenuitem`" is always null, and exception is thrown.

Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: In this case, the `as` has done it's job. It's not a `ToolStripMenuItem`, and you've checked for this. When you debug, step through it to manually evaluate the type of sender and you'll see it isn't of a type you're expecting it to be. I'd also refactor this a little bit to use `is` instead of `as`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

frmMain_FormClosing is attached to the Form, not to the ToolStripMenuItem, so the sender is the Form.

`sender as ToolStripMenuItem` will return null.
`sender as Form` will return the form.

Answer (score 2):

sender here is a Form itself.  That is why the problem appears.  To implement this task, you need to create a property in the form and set its value when you call the Form's Close method.  Then check this property value and show messages as required.

Another solution would be to create a new method and use it when you need to close it:

```
protected void CloseCore(object control) {
  // show message base on the control
  Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `as` keyword does an attempted cast on reference types only and returns null if the cast fails (including when the item itself is already null). This differs from explicit casting in that no exception is thrown on a failed cast.

You simply need to check for nulls. In this case, a `ToolStripMenuItem` will *never* be the sender for this event.

Using that keyword, your code is potentially unsafe as you do your cast assuming it will pass by immediately trying to access a member:

```
(sender as ToolStripMenuItem).Name == "";
```

Sometimes assuming it will pass is fine, I do that ocassionally when I know what it will do. In the general case however, you'll likely want to null check:

```
var typedSender = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;

if (typedSender != null && typedSender.Name == "")
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `as` keyword will try and cast the object against the type and return either the cast instance or `null` if the instance cannot be cast.

You need to do something like this:

```
private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var toolStripMenuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;

    if (toolStripMenuItem !=null && toolStripMenuItem .Name == @"exitToolStripMenuItem")
    { 
    }
}
```

In your case you also have another problem which is that your `exitToolStripMenuItem` handler is calling `Form.Close()` which means that the `sender` in `frmMain_FormClosing(object sender` will always be the form.